# alguna idea como seleccionar un numeros redondos en sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net

alguno tiene alguna idea de como seleccionar de una tabla números redondos. Se le agradecería un ejemplo o alguna idea  así puedo implementarlo en mi BD GRACIAS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Y si utilizas un ROUND en el campo que deseas redondear y así detalladas el tipo de redondeo que necesitas.

ROUND ( numeric_expression , length [ ,function ] )
Select Round(@Numero, 2, 0)

Ese ejemplo es de un redondeo a 2 decimales .

Answer (score 1):

Hay muchas maneras de seleccionar números *redondos* de una tabla, todo depende de que sea lo que busques o entiendas por número *redondo*.

Por ejemplo, con las siguientes funciones:

- [`round()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): Realiza un *redondeo* de acuerdo al número de decimales (o de múltiplos de 10) que se pasa como parámetro
- [`cast()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): Lo utilizo para convertir un número de coma flotante en un entero (que siempre es *redondo*)
- [`floor()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/floor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): Tiene el mismo efecto que `cast()`, quizás quede más claro que siempre ignora la parte decimal, es decir *trunca* el número, no necesariamente lo *redondea* (pero si que devuelve un número redondo).
- [`ceiling()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ceiling-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): Devuelve también un entero, pero siempre es el *techo* del número que se pasa, es decir, `1.0` devuelve `1`, pero `1.001` devuelve `2`.

Encontrarás más información en la documentación enlazada. Te dejo algunos ejemplos:

```
with 
A as (
          select 76.13456 Numero
union all select 151.50 
union all select 49.0199999
)
select   Numero
       , ROUND(Numero, 2) NumeroCon2Decimales
       , ROUND(Numero, 0) NumeroComaFlotanteCon0Decimales
       , ROUND(Numero, -1) NumeroAMultiplosde10
       , CAST(Numero as int) NumeroEnteroTruncado1
       , FLOOR(Numero) NumeroEnteroTruncado2
       , CEILING(Numero) NumeroEnteroSuperior
  from A;
```

Que produce esta salida:

```
Numero       NumeroCon2Decimales NumeroComaFlotanteCon0Decimales NumeroAMultiplosde10 NumeroEnteroTruncado1 NumeroEnteroTruncado2 NumeroEnteroSuperior
------------ ------------------- ------------------------------- -------------------- --------------------- --------------------- --------------------
76.1345600   76.1300000          76.0000000                      80.0000000           76                    76                    77
151.5000000  151.5000000         152.0000000                     150.0000000          151                   151                   152
49.0199999   49.0200000          49.0000000                      50.0000000           49                    49                    50

(3 row(s) affected)
```